# How to compile & use GLib with MinGW

Tags: windows, glib, mingw32

I want to use the [Gnome GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/) in a Windows environment using the free MinGW compiler to develop in C. The problem is, I have absolutely no idea how to compile this library. Would any of you please explain what tools are needed to accomplish this and what instructions need to be followed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use MSys, it is downloadable from MinGW site. Using MSys you will be able to build GLib: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_GLIB_with_MinGW

Comment: Nice link, that will definitely help! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the link is gone in history, so as the old MinGW website. New one is [here](http://mingw-w64.org). I'd suggest you to use precompiled library as other answer suggests. Another option would be to search trough MinGW mailing list. Good luck!

Answer (score 12):

GLib is available pre-compiled for Windows and has been for ages: http://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php.

Comment: As a note, glib seems to have stopped released pre-built binaries for windows after 2.28

Comment: I think glib 2.34+ binaries are available [here](http://win32builder.gnome.org/), but before I knew of this, downloading MSYS (from the answer's link) and installing the cross compiled version with pacman worked out well.  (details of which packages [here](https://github.com/lcm-proj/lcm/issues/99))